# python selenium click on mat-radio-group fails

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, radio-button

I'm trying to click on a radio button using python selelnium but I receive error. The html code of the radio button is this:

```
<mat-radio-button class="mat-radio-button mat-accent" value="false" tabindex="-1" id="mat-radio-3">
   <label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-3-input">
      <div class="mat-radio-container">
         <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
         <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
         <div class="mat-radio-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="">
            <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div>
         </div>
         <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-3-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-0" value="false">
      </div>
      <div class="mat-radio-label-content">
         <span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span> دیده بان 
      </div>
   </label>
</mat-radio-button>
```

I want to click on that id="mat-radio-3" or id="mat-radio-3-input".

I tried with this code on both elements using their XPATH:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-radio-3"]')))
   if myElem != None:
      myElem.click()
```

So I expected that the radio button is clicked and checked but instead I received the following error on both elements:

```
Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF64A9E2762+56978]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A95AB92]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A82EEBB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A86819E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A86828C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A89F5B7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A885BFF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A89D662]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A885993]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A85D7B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A85E994]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF64AC95D82+2888882]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF64ACE9A08+3232056]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF64ACE281F+3202895]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF64AA76915+663621]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A9664B8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A962434]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A96252C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF64A9528B3]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9CEDE7614+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9D06E26B1+33]
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Try this one.

myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mat-radio-3-input')))
   if myElem != None:
      myElem.click()

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to your suggestion then I received this error:
Message: element click intercepted: Element `<input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="mat-radio-3-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-0" value="false"> is not clickable at point (2392, 126). Other element would receive the click: <div class="mat-radio-container">...</div>`

So I changed it again to this div that in this message has been mentioned and it worked.
`myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-radio-3"]/label/div[1]')))`